# When does pickle fail to pickle an instance?

Tags: python, instance, pickle

I have a python class which I can instantiate and then pickle.  But then I have a second class, inheriting from the first, whose instances I cannot pickle.  Pickle gives me the error "can't pickle instancemethod".  Both instances have plenty of methods.  So, does anyone have a guess as to why the first class would pickle OK, but not the second?  I'm sure that you will want to see the code, but it's pretty lengthy and I really have no idea what the "offending" parts of the second class might be.  So I can't show the whole thing and I don't really know what the relevant parts might be.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled

Comment: @Joran Beasley  Thanks, but honestly, if I had understood that document, I would not have come here.  Am I supposed to write __dict__ or __getstate__ methods?  If so, what exactly, do they do.  Thanks again.

Comment: Comment all methods and then uncomment one by one and try to pickle it. By doing this you can eliminate which method breaks serialization.

Answer (score 1):

There's a pretty extensive list of what can and can't be pickled here:
https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill/blob/master/dill/_objects.py

It lists all objects through the first 15 or so sections in the python standard library, and while it's not everything, it also covers all of the objects of primary and many of the secondary importance in the standard library.

Also, if you decide to use `dill` instead of `pickle`, I'm going to guess that you probably won't have a pickling issue, as `dill` can pretty much serialize anything in python.

More directly addressing your question… `pickle` pickles classes by reference, while `dill` pickles classes code *or* by reference, depending on the setting you choose (default is to pickle the code).  This can bypass "lookup" issues for class references that `pickle` has.

Answer (score 0):

Pickling simply doesnt pickle your classes, pickle only works on data, if you try to pickle a class with built in methods it simply will not work. it will come out glitchy and broken.

source: learning python by Mark Lutz